# Program exists when using the Play method in SoundPlayer

Tags: c#, soundplayer

When I use the Play method with the SoundPlayer, my program exits and there is no sound playing. Please help me.

Code:

```
SoundPlayer player;
player = new SoundPlayer();

private void wii_WiimoteChanged(object s, EventArgs e)
{
  if (wii.WiimoteState.GuitarState.FretButtonState.Green == true)
  {
     Play(1);
  }
}

private void Play(int soundID)
{
  player.SoundLocation = "sounds/" + soundID + ".wav";
  player.Load();
}

private void player_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   player.Play();
}
```

Comment: Provide more context - when is this code executed? Are debugging the application, or just running it from the console/explorer?

Comment: try using player.Load(), and enabling "Play" only as a callback when load is done

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx

Init player

```
player = new SoundPlayer();
player.LoadCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(player_LoadCompleted);
```

Load a file

```
player.SoundLocation = "sounds/" + soundID + ".wav";
player.Load();
```

On load finished play

```
private void player_LoadCompleted(object sender, 
AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{   
        player.Play();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But it still exit the program.Do you have another solution?

Comment: can you add more code? what kind of program you are running, where your code fits in there

Answer (score 0):

try with full path

```
player.SoundLocation = Path.GetFullPath("sounds/" + soundID + ".wav");
```

sample code:

```
using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Path.GetFullPath("sounds/" + soundID + ".wav")))
{
    player.PlaySync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But it still exit the program.Do you have another solution?